# CAML Query SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, caml

Hi i am trying to write a caml query query for the below statement,

(City="A" || FirstName="A" || LastName="A" ) && (color="red" || color="green"|| color="blue"|| color="violet")

This is the CAMl Query i have written but its not working

```
<Query><Where><And><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name='City' /><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></Contains><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name='FirstName' /><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></Contains><Contains><FieldRef Name='LastName' /><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></Contains></Or></Or></And><And><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name='Color' /><Value Type='Text'>Red</Value></Contains><Or>
```

GreenBlueViolet

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added an Incomplete CAML query, The exact query you need is :

```
<Query><Where><And><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name='City' /><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></Contains><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name='FirstName' /><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></Contains><Contains><FieldRef Name='LastName' /><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></Contains></Or></Or><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name='Color' /><Value Type='Text'>red</Value></Contains><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name='Color' /><Value Type='Text'>green</Value></Contains><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name='Color' /><Value Type='Text'>blue</Value></Contains><Contains><FieldRef Name='Color' /><Value Type='Text'>violet</Value></Contains></Or></Or></Or></And></Where></Query>
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: If you want to build complex query you can use the tool _U2U CAML Builder_ from the below site [link]http://www.u2u.be/Software

Answer (score 0):

Please Try to use below query it may help you.

```html
<Query>
<Where>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <eq><FieldRef Name='City' /><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></eq>
            <OR>
                <eq><FieldRef Name='FirstName' /><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></eq>
                <OR>
                    <eq><FieldRef Name='LastName' /><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></eq>
                </OR>
            </OR>
        </Or>

        <Or>
            <In>
                <FieldRef Name="color" />
                <Values>
                    <Value Type='Text'>red</Value>
                    <Value Type='Text'>green</Value>
                    <Value Type='Text'>blue</Value>
                </Values>
            </In>
        </Or>
    </And>
</Where>
</Query>
```